# android. use LibVLC for play video format hdr10, after some time dialog isn`t responding

Tags: android

Использую библиотеку от VLC  ---  LibVLC.

проигрываю видеофайл формата hdr10 (возможно очень сильно требовательный к ресурсам),

через некоторое время отобразился диалог на экране, "isn`t responding"
с предложением закрыть или подождать.

Можно ли как то избавиться от данной ошибки.

Может что то в системе настроить или в программе какой то ключ добавить.

пример кода.

ArrayList options = new ArrayList();

```
            options.add("--aout=opensles");
            options.add("--audio-time-stretch"); // time stretching
            options.add("-vvv"); // verbosity
            options.add("--http-reconnect");
            options.add("--network-caching=" + 6 * 1000);
            libvlc = new LibVLC(options);
            //libvlc.setOnHardwareAccelerationError(this);
            surfaceHolder.setKeepScreenOn(true);

            // Create media player
            mediaPlayer = new org.videolan.libvlc.MediaPlayer(libvlc);
            mediaPlayer.setEventListener(myPlayerListener);

            // Set up video output
            final IVLCVout mediaPlayerVLCVout = mediaPlayer.getVLCVout();
            mediaPlayerVLCVout.setVideoView(surfaceView);
            //vout.setSubtitlesView(mSurfaceSubtitles);
            mediaPlayerVLCVout.addCallback(this);
            mediaPlayerVLCVout.attachViews();


            Media media = new Media(libvlc, Uri.parse(uri));
            mediaPlayer.setMedia(media);
            mediaPlayer.play();
```

Comment: Я понимаю, что Вам некогда, но также некогда и людям, которые могут Вам ответить. ИМХО, несколько вводных слов по русски проясняющих суть проблемы ускорят получение ответа https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask